# Use bootstrap using @types/bootstrap in angular 2/4 project

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

How can we use bootstrap with @types/bootstrap in angular Project using angular CLI.I am following these steps

1. npm install jquery bootstrap bootbox @types/bootstrap @types/jquery @types/bootbox.

   import * as $ from 'jquery';

   import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

   import * as bootbox from "bootbox";
2. When I am trying to open bootbox.alert using the following statement
   bootbox.alert("message") its giving an error

   $.fn.modal is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngbootstrap

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```